# ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' at Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: permissions, mysql, lamp

I have followed this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-ubuntu-18-04) to install MySQL but after successfully installed MySQL, I could not access database.

> ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Comment: I faced the same issue, after some digging, got it that u have to set root password your self following instructions at the [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42153059/mysqld-safe-directory-var-run-mysqld-for-unix-socket-file-dont-exists).

Answer (score 81, accepted):

I found a solution at here [link](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/03/16/change-user-password-in-mysql-5-7-with-plugin-auth_socket/), by following this solution I have solved my problem.

Short steps are:

```
sudo mysql -u root
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'test';
```

Note: here `test` is a new password for the root user. Also, remember to run the command `sudo service mysql restart` after altering the user.

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'b230mehonot'' at line 1

Comment: same error here... :(

Comment: @alhelal, The solution is for MySQL not for MariaDB. So you can try another solution.

Comment: Do not write mysql -u root, Just write "sudo mysql", In Ubuntu systems running MySQL 5.7 (and later), the root user is authenticated by the auth_socket plugin by default.

Comment: @ravisoni - **THANK YOU**. I was going **nuts**. And: What a reasonable default. I really should have thought to try that...

Comment: to reset a `mysql` password this is a simple solution which works.  pragmatic.

Answer (score 26):

I found another way that is much better as we need not to give any password for local system. 
It is as followed.

Open terminal and type

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

It will prompt you in mysql, here you can fire any mysql commands.

Use mysql table for change table type, so we can use empty password. Bellow is command for it

```
USE mysql;
```

Now we change type of table by following command

```
UPDATE user SET plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root';
```

now we have to flush the privileges, because we have used UPDATE. If you use INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE on **grant tables** directly you need use FLUSH PRIVILEGES in order to reload the grant tables.

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

now exit from mysql by following command

```
exit;
```

now restart mysql server by following command

```
service mysql restart
```

Hope this may help

Thank you.

Comment: This is the right answer

Comment: How "It will prompt you in mysql", if the error is that it's not logging in at all?!!

Comment: in my case it always prompt in terminal you can also try