# ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: permissions, mysql, 18.04, mariadb

```
alhelal@VimLaTeX:~$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
alhelal@VimLaTeX:~$ sudo mysql -u root -p
[sudo] password for alhelal: 
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 35
Server version: 10.1.29-MariaDB-6 Ubuntu 18.04

Copyright (c) 2000, 2017, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

Why mariadb doesn't allow normal ubuntu user to enter mysql as mysql root user?

I also tried [ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' at Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029177/error-1698-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-at-ubuntu-18-04) but failed?

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'test'' at line 1
```

Comment: Are you still facing this issue? Which SQL query you used in which you got syntax error?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42742610/4468423) from SO, it could be because your root user is using the `auth_socket` plugin used by default in MySQL/MariaDB on Ubuntu.

```
$ sudo mysql -u root

MariaDB [mysql]> USE mysql;
MariaDB [mysql]> SELECT User, Host, plugin FROM mysql.user;

+------------------+-----------------------+
| User             | plugin                |
+------------------+-----------------------+
| root             | auth_socket           |
+------------------+-----------------------+
```

Changing this to `mysql_native_password` will allow you to connect without requiring `sudo`:

```
$ sudo mysql -u root

MariaDB [mysql]> USE mysql;
MariaDB [mysql]> UPDATE user SET plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root';
MariaDB [mysql]> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
MariaDB [mysql]> exit;

$ service mysql restart
```